# JSP + Iteration Output

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to iterate through a list of Birthdate objects. Inside this object there are 2 variables. A Date object for the birthdate itself and a String for a partially masked date (ie. --/--/2015)

The When portion is working fine and displaying the date properly but when testing out the Otherwise portion I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert --/--/1956 of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date
```

Am I just missing something totally obvious here? From the examples I've found this should be possible. Below is my code:

```
<c:choose>   
 <c:when test="${person.showBirthDates}"> 
    <c:forEach var="bdate" items="${person.birthdates}" varStatus="status">
    <fmt:formatDate value="${bdate.birthdate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
    </td> </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>
    </c:forEach>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <c:forEach var="bdate" items="${person.birthdates}" varStatus="status">
    <c:out value= "${bdate.birthdateMask}" />
    </td> </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>
    </c:forEach>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Uhm maybe it always select the first path even if person.showBIrthDates is false.

Comment: Can you post your Person class source code?

Comment: @ John - The "Person" (not its real name, but close enough) class is huge. (~1500 lines) Is there anything specific you're looking for? It extends another class which is where the Birthdate list is defined if that makes any difference. 

@Marco - Why might it be doing that? I've used when/otherwise in a number of other places in my code and they work just fine. I know the boolean is getting set properly because without the setting code I placed in, nothing happens at all for this entry.

Comment: @all - Additionally, I tried replaced <c:out value ={bdate.birthdateMask}" /> with just ***** and it's actually returning the same error I posted above. So the idea that I might not be even getting into the otherwise still may have merit. I'm just confused as to why...

Comment: The missing `"` in the line `<c:out value= ${bdate.birthdateMask}" />` is a copy-paste error right?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I'll edit that to fix it.

Comment: Do you even need to use the `birthdateMask` field?  Seems to me you could just do `<fmt:formatDate value="${bdate.birthdate}" pattern="--/--/yyyy"/>`